# null-sources on mallet composition file

Tags: machine-learning, information-retrieval, topic-modeling, mallet, topicmodels

I want to use mallet for training topics. My data are in a single file, So I study mallet documentation to how construct this One Single file.

In [Mallet website](http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/import.php), under the **One file, one instance per line** section, It was said:

> [URL]  [language]  [text of the page...]
>
> In this case, the first token
>   of each line (whitespace delimited, with optional comma) becomes the
>   instance name, the second token becomes the label, and all additional
>   text on the line is interpreted as a sequence of word tokens.

So according to the above quote, I created my single file in this way:

```
127  en  some text here...
982  en  some text here...
1003  en  some text here...
...
```

and then import this single file:

```
bin\mallet import-file --input data.txt --output data.mallet --keep-sequence
```

after that, I train 3 topics:

```
bin\mallet train-topics --input data.mallet --num-topics 3 --output-doc-topics data_composition.txt --word-topic-counts-file data_wcounts.txt
```

However, When I open the `data_composition.txt`, it has the following structure:

```
#doc source topic proportion ...    
0 null-source 0 0.4057970941066742 1 0.3188405930995941 2 0.2753623127937317
```

So now the question is: Why does mallet print `null-source` on this composition file? I want it prints the URL (i.e. IDs in my case) under the source heading.

**EDIT:**

I want something like this:

```
#doc source topic proportion ...    
0     127   0 0.4057970941066742 1 0.3188405930995941 2 0.2753623127937317 
1     982    ... (topic probabilities) ...
2     1003   ... (topic probabilities) ...
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The first column of your input file does not contain URLs. Try

```
file://0
```

instead of just `0`.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply, Regarding your reply, The numbers (1,2,3 , etc) are the URLs expected by mallet. In the other words, How can I tell mallet that numbers are the URLs? Do you know? @jknappen

Comment: The numbers in the first column of the "composition" file are just line numbers, counting from 0. They don't have any relation to the document URL's, to appear in the second column.

Comment: I gave that numbers randomly (they're not line numbers) I myself gave that numbers. For more clarification pay attention to edited post. @jknappen

Comment: Look, I want mallet prints URL's under of source heading in composition file. For instance, `127` should be printed in the second line of composition file

Comment: I suggest that you feed mallet with **real URLs** and do some postprocessing afterwards to tweak the file format.

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading to the latest Mallet version here: http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/download.php

Mallet instances have a "name" and a "source" field. In previous versions, the `--output-doc-topics` printed the source. The current stable version, 2.0.8, prints the name, which is the field you want to display.

Note that this version also defaults to a "dense" representation of topic proportions, with one column for each topic.